# How to open html in cmd shell

Tags: shell, google-chrome, cmd

How to find an html file and open it in Chrome. I used to combine

start chrome (dir /b/s *.html)
but not working

So how I could first find a file html and open it in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use dir in a loop?

If you need some "index.html" in some sub-folder "GFExperience", above a sample code for this:

```bat
:: command line
for /f "tokens=*delims=\" %i in ('dir /b/s *.html ^| find /i "GFExperience" ^| find /i "index.html"')do pushd "%~pi" && start chrome.exe -tab "%i" && popd

:: bat file
for /f "tokens=*delims=\" %%i in ('dir /b/s *.html ^| find /i "GFExperience" ^| find /i "index.html"')do pushd "%%~pi" && start chrome.exe -tab "%%i" && popd
```